# java app runs well in "info" mode and throws exception in "debug" mode of Logback

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, log4j, logback

I use default logger for spring boot apps - Logback. As I know Logback natively implements the SLF4J API.

My spring boot app works well when I use logging mode "info" or "error", but throws this exception in "debug" mode (when app is starting):

```
    07:17:41.884 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
...
...
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
        at com.ric.web.BillWebApplication.main(BillWebApplication.java:40)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.pretty.MessageHelper.collectionInfoString(MessageHelper.java:264)
        at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:267)
... 16 common frames omitted
```

My config bean PostConstruct method:

```
@PostConstruct
private void setUp() throws EmptyStorable {
    Obj obj = objMng.getByCD("Модуль начисления");
    calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.clear(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);

    obj.getDw().size(); <---Exception here!

    calendar.setTime(parMng.getDate(obj, "Begin"));
    setCurDt1(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.setTime(parMng.getDate(obj, "End"));
    setCurDt2(calendar.getTime());
    String yy = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String mm = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    mm = "0"+mm;
    mm = mm.substring(mm.length()-2, mm.length());
    setPeriod(yy+mm);
    setCntCurDays(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    setPartDays(1/getCntCurDays());
}
```

My logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- Log message format -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- Setting the root level of logging to INFO -->
  <root level="debug"> <--here I was changing logging mode 
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ric.bill</groupId>
    <artifactId>BillWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

        <start-class>com.rrr.bill2</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Support for Ehcache and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/c3p0/c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
              </configuration>                

              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target> 
                                <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
                                    update="true" compress="store">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes"
                                        includes="com/ric/web/Bootstrap.class" />
                                </zip>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

If I remove problem lines of code from the @PostConstruct method, I get another exception in other parts of application.

I can't understand strange behavior of my app, when I switch modes of loggings...

**Upd 1**

I found out that bag variable is null in method:

```
@Override
public int size() {
    return readSize() ? getCachedSize() : bag.size();
}
```

of hibernate PersistentBag.class

full error stack:

```
08:51:16.237 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at com.ric.web.BillWebApplication.main(BillWebApplication.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.pretty.MessageHelper.collectionInfoString(MessageHelper.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2152)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.size(PersistentBag.java:261)
    at com.ric.bill.Config.setUp(Config.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
08:51:16.241 [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] DEBUG c.m.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@3a2da38 closed by a client.
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG -- CLOSE BY CLIENT STACK TRACE
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:566)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:234)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:470)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:964)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:989)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1174)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might be a bug in Hibernate 5.1.0.Final.  Have you thought about submitting a bug report, along with an isolated test case to replicate the issue?

[Here is where the debug logging occurs](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/loading/internal/CollectionLoadContext.java#L267): so yes, you need to have debug logging enabled to exercise this code path.

[Here is where](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.1/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/pretty/MessageHelper.java#L264) the `NullPointerException` is being thrown.

Have you tried stepping through `MessageHelper.java` with a debugger to see what exactly is causing the NPE?

As a workaround, disable debug logging for `CollectionLoadContext.java` in Hibernate by adding the following line to your Logback configuration file:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext" level="INFO"/>
```

Comment: ck1, see my Upd-1

Comment: I've updated my answer with a workaround.  This is all I can think of to prevent the `NullPointerException` while logging at the `DEBUG` level.